# Get URL of background-image ONLY from inline style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Fairly simple, I need to know if a custom image has been added to overwrite the default, and if it has to get its url.

(The custom image will always be added via inline style)

I'm ok with parsing the url out of the property, I just need to only get this if it's inline.

**Update**

I have an idea that I didn't want to propose at first to keep all ideas on the table.

I check the element for `` `.indexOf("background-image") `` after getting `.attr('style')` and if this `!== -1` then I get `.css('backgroundImage')` and parse the url out with regex.

I'm just not convinced this is the best solution, but it is working.

Comment: Did you mean an image as a background?

Comment: Well, I have something slightly jury rigged working. I check the .attr('style') for indexOf background-image, and if it isn't -1 I get the .css('backgroundImage') and parse the URL with a regex.

Comment: Whats wrong with the solution you just described? You're looking for something simpler?

Comment: @WillNelson Yeah, I'm questioning whether it's a good approach for this. It might be the best way to go, I'm just not convinced.

Comment: I was just about to propose the solution you just described. I recommend adding that to your question. You're really asking if there's a better way than your current one.

Answer (score 2):

You could:

```
var elem = $("div");

if(elem.attr("style").search("background-image") > -1){
   console.log(elem[0].style.backgroundImage)
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uJ3Nm/